# WP Linkedin Recommendations Scroller not working

Tags: wordpress, linkedin-api

I am using WP Linkedin plugin to fetch Recommendations from Linkedin but the Recommendations scroller not working for me. It shows recommendation properply but not scrolls. Need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with other scripts on my page. Thats why scroller was not working. Now working fine.